# jquery 1.9. [value!=""] selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.9

I need value is not empty selector to count if at least 2 inputs with a name choices[] were filled. I had before jquery 1.7.2 and not value!="" selector worked.

```
$('input[name="choices[]"][value!=""]').length
```

Now I upgraded do jquery 1.9.1 and this always returns the number of all fields as all fields were filled, even if none of them were filled. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

That's not working anymore because there's a difference between the *current* value of a field and the `value` attribute (which typically holds the *original* value as of when the HTML was parsed).

You'll probably have to throw a [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/#not-functionindex) in there:

```
$('input[name="choices[]"]').not(function() {
    return !!this.value;
}).length
```

...or [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter):

```
$('input[name="choices[]"]').not(function() {
    return !this.value;
}).length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
$('input[name="choices[]"]').filter(function() {
     return $(this).val() != "";
}).length
```